# Integrability condition for a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields, integrable-systems

The Frobenius theorem says that for two vector fields $X,Y$  to be compatible it is sufficient to show that for some functions $\alpha ,\beta$ the following equation holds true
\begin{equation}
\alpha X + \beta Y + [X,Y] = 0
\end{equation}
Assume the two function $\alpha, \beta$ are given, what is the link to the **integrability condition ?**

As an example, I would like to understand it for the easiest case in  $\mathbb{R}^2$. Given the vector fields $X= X^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial X^1}$ and $Y= X^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial X^2}$ with $\alpha=X^2 \frac{\partial X^1}{\partial X^2}$ and $\beta=-X^1 \frac{\partial X^2}{\partial X^1}$ how do I proceed? Do I need to provide more information?

I believe that the solution should be something like the following equation, but unsure as to why.
\begin{equation}
 (X^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial X^1})(\beta X^2)-(X^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial X^2})(\alpha X^1)=0
\end{equation}

In [Introduction to smooth manifolds](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9982-5) by John M. Lee on page 510 this topic is approached from the angle of *Overdetermined Systems of Partial Differential Equations*, but I can not bridge the gap between these two topics.

There is also the exterior algebra approach by Robert L. Bryant in [Exterior Differential Systems](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461397168), first mentioned on page 60 and during Cartan-Kähler Theory, where I am hoping to arrive eventually.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you might need to go to three dimensions to see anything interesting. In the plane, if $X$ and $Y$ are *any* linearly independent vector fields, then their Lie bracket $[X,Y]$, being a vector field in the plane too, can be expressed as a linear combination of $X$ and $Y$, giving you the functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Yes, they are linear independent. I used this easy non-trivial example to get a quick transparent solution for the integrability equation/condition. Which should be also possible in 2D I think. Or are you saying that the solutions for $\alpha , \beta$ are the integrability condition. If so, how does this yield in one equation, as mentioned in most books?

Comment: I don't follow you at all. What do you mean by “the integrability condition”? This can mean several things, but what I think of in this case is the Frobenius integrability condition: if you have a distribution spanned by vector field, it's integrable if the Lie bracket of any pair of these vector fields lies in the distribution. Which in the case of a two-dimensional distribution is just your first equation.

Comment: By integrability condition, I mean something along the lines of this classic example from pde. If $u_x = A(x,y,u)$ and $u_y = B(x,y,u)$ then the integrability condition is $A_y + B A_u = B_x +A B_u$. I want to translate this notion to my problem, but have the impression that I am missing a function analogous to the here presented $u$.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the text can be seen as determined be the first equation.

Comment: I think this might just be two different uses of the phrase “integrability condition”. Like “What's the condition for us to be able to integrate this PDE?” and “What's the condition for us to be able to integrate the distribution spanned by these vector fields?”. Maybe there's a deeper connection, but I don't see it at once anyway.